# WebdriverIO - How can I create a map variable that can be updated and accessed between all test instances?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, dictionary, webdriver-io

Is it possible to create a global map variable that can be updated and accessed between all test instances in a WebdriverIO project?

I'm making API calls that return an ID for each capability configuration, but the IDs need to be stored in a key/value variable that can be accessed by all test instances so that duplicate IDs are not created and so that the same IDs can be used by tests using the same capabilities.

This is how I was trying to implement my idea for making the API calls:

```
let axios = require('axios');
global.IDs = new Map();

let API = Object.create(null, {

    getID: {
        value: async function (cid, json) {

            let key = cid.split("-")[0];

            if(global.IDs.has(key)){
                return global.IDs.get(key);
            } else {
                let config = {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: /*redacted*/,
                    headers: { 
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    },
                    data: json
                };
                await axios(config).then(function (response) {
                    global.IDs.set(key, response.data.id);
                    return response.data.id;
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    return null;
                });
            }
        }
    },

});

module.exports = API;
```

Notice the `global.IDs` map variable that should store the IDs.  When executing multiple tests, the `global.IDs` variable is always displayed as empty despite pushing key/value pairs.  This is what the execution looks like when I print the process:

```
// Bad results :(
[0-0] global.IDs = []
[0-0] cid = 0
map does not have cid = 0
[0-0] ID returned = 495
[0-0] new global.IDs = [ [ '0', 495 ] ]
[0-1] global.IDs = []
[0-1] cid = 0
map does not have cid = 0
[0-1] ID returned = 496
[0-1] new global.IDs = [ [ '0', 496 ] ]
[1-0] global.IDs = []
[1-0] cid = 1
map does not have cid = 1
[1-0] ID returned = 497
[1-0] new global.IDs = [ [ '1', 497 ] ]
[1-1] global.IDs = []
[1-1] cid = 1
map does not have cid = 1
[1-1] ID returned = 498
[1-1] new global.IDs = [ [ '1', 498 ] ]
```

Ultimately, the execution should look like this:

```
//Good results :)
[0-0] global.IDs = []
[0-0] cid = 0
map does not have cid = 0
[0-0] ID returned = 495
[0-0] new global.IDs = [ [ '0', 495 ] ]
[0-1] global.IDs = [ [ '0', 495 ] ]
[0-1] cid = 0
map has cid = 0
returning value = 495
[1-0] global.IDs = [ [ '0', 495 ] ]
[1-0] cid = 1
map does not have cid = 1
[1-0] ID returned = 496
[1-0] new global.IDs = [ [ '0', 495 ], [ '1', 496 ] ]
[1-1] global.IDs = [ [ '0', 495 ], [ '1', 496 ] ]
[1-1] cid = 1
map has cid = 1
returning value = 496
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, I also need a global variable. I declared this variable in the **beforeSuite** hook in the **wdio.conf.js** file and it is available in all tests.

**wdio.conf.js**

```
beforeSuite: function (suite) {
  var test = {a: 1}
  global.test = test
}
```

**My test file**

```
describe('temp test ', () ->
  it('temp test', () ->
    console.log('test = ', test)
  )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help my issue. When implementing your suggestion, it throws an error that says that the global variable does not exist (or rather is undefined).  I believe this is happening because my global variable needs to be accessed within my Custom Reporter, not an actual test case.  Thank you for trying though! I really do appreciate it.